# OpenGL - texelFetch fetches nothing

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to draw a textured plane following the OpenGL SuperBible 6th ed. but for some reason I fail.

Here's my texture initialization code.

```
GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
int w = 256;
int h = 256;
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA32F, w, h);
float * data = new float[w * h * 4];
//This just creates some image data
generateTexture(data, w, h);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, data);
delete [] data;
```

This is the plane object. The object itself is drawn, just untextured.

```
glGenBuffers(1, &planeBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, planeBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
             sizeof(planePositions),
             planePositions,
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

These are my vertex and fragment shaders.

```
#version 430 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
uniform mat4 proj, view;
void main(void){      
      gl_Position = proj * view * vec4 (position, 1.0);      
}


#version 430 core
uniform sampler2D s;
out vec4 frag_color;
void main () {
    frag_color = texelFetch(s, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0);
};
```

I draw like this

```
glUseProgram(textureProgram);

GLuint projLocation = glGetUniformLocation (textureProgram, "proj");
glUniformMatrix4fv (projLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, projectionSource);

GLuint viewLocation = glGetUniformLocation (textureProgram, "view");
glUniformMatrix4fv (viewLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, viewSource);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, planeBuffer);
GLuint positionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(textureProgram, "position");
glVertexAttribPointer (positionLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);               
glEnableVertexAttribArray (positionLocation);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);    
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);                 
GLuint ts = glGetUniformLocation (textureProgram, "s");
glUniform1i(ts, 0);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
glDisableVertexAttribArray (positionLocation);                           

//Afterwards I draw more geometry with other shaders. This shows correctly
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
//Bind buffers, matrices, drawarrays, etc
```

But I just get a black untextured plane. If I override the `frag_color` assignment by adding another line afterwards, like so

```
frag_color = vec4(1.0);
```

it works, i.e. I get a white plane, so the shaders seem to be working correctly.

I don't get any errors whatsoever from `glGetError()`.

Compatibility:

```
OpenGL version supported: 4.2.12337 Compatibility Profile Context 13.101
GLSL version supported: 4.30
```

The `data` array does contain values between 0 and 1. I have also tried hard-coding some random coordinates into the `texelFetch()` function, but I always get a black plane. It looks as though the `sampler2D` contained nothing but zeroes. I have also tried hard-coding the values contained in `data` to `1.0`, `255.0`, but nothing.

Either the book fails to mention something or I am missing something stupid. Why does the texture refuse to show on the plane?

**EDIT:** I added some code to the drawing part. The rest of the geometry that I draw (with different shaders) shows perfectly. None of it uses textures.

Comment: The second parameter in texelFetch should be between 0 and 1. gl_FragCoord gives you the pixel coordinates between 0 and your screen resolution.

Comment: @dari Doesn't `ivec2` represent a vector of integers?

Comment: @dari Anyway, if I divide the gl_FragCoord coordinates by the screen dimensions I still get nothing.

Comment: try texture() instead of texelFetch() and vec2 instead of ivec2

Comment: Same problem with `texture()` and `vec2`.

Comment: Did you bind the texture correctly? Bind texture to a texture unit and pass this texture unit to the sampler uniform.

Comment: I did what you can see on the code, which is pretty much what the book says. Is that code insufficient? I never pass it explicitly to the uniform.

Comment: Look here how to bind textures: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605480/opengl-4-0-texture-binding

Comment: Nothing. Even if I bind explicitly as shown in the link the plane remains black.

Comment: The location of the uniform returned is correct (2) and no errors show.

Comment: Try adding a `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)`. The default sampling parameters are to sample with mipmaps, and you don't have mipmaps.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Nothing. Still black.

Comment: I think there is too much of yoour state setup and drawing code missing to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @broncoAbierto: What I suggested actually doesn't matter for `texelFetch()`. It would if you sample with `texture()`.

Comment: @derhass Ok, I'll edit and add some info. I'll favor explanation over code at first, because there's too much of it.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Ok. When I try to use texture() or texture2d() (with normalized coords) it doesn't work either.

Comment: @broncoAbierto: Your `glActiveTexture()` call comes to late, you must do it before binding the texture. But that will only be the culprit if you switch the active texture unit somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @derhass I just noticed that, and no, I don't change the active texture elsewhere, so not the culprit.

Comment: I got my way around it. I'll post it as an answer. Thanks to everyone that commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got my way around this, although it is not clear what the problem is exactly.

I got the texture to show using `glTexImage2D` instead of `glTexStorage2D` and `glTexSubImage2D`.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, data);
```

I also had to set the parameters explicitly, even though I'm using `texelFetch()`.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Binding the uniform explicitly was not necessary.

What is strange is that, according to the docs, `glTexStorage2D`is equivalent to this:

```
for (i = 0; i < levels; i++) {
    glTexImage2D(target, i, internalformat, width, height, 0, format, type, NULL);
    width = max(1, (width / 2));
    height = max(1, (height / 2));
}
```

However, this combination does not work.

```
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA, w, h);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, data);
```

I still have to figure out why is that, but at least I got it to work.

Comment: Why it doesn't work with these parameters can be explained. `glTexStorage2D()` does not accept unsized internal formats, so passing `GL_RGBA` is an error. You would need a sized format like `GL_RGBA8`. What I don't understand is why it didn't work in your original code, because `GL_RGBA32F` is a valid argument. Did you try using `glGetError()` in the original code, and see if it complains about anything?

Comment: I see. I got no errors from `glGetError()`, but I'll fiddle with `glTexStorage2D()` and try to get it to work using that set of funtions.

Comment: Someone said you need set `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, x);`,and it will work I think, why? I don't know.